# Collection of domain of a set of functions

Tags: set-theory

I am studying ZFC set theory using some [lecture notes](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://ocw.metu.edu.tr/pluginfile.php/99015/mod_resource/content/1/320lecturenotes.pdf) I found online and they contain the following exercise:

[image]

Now, I think I know how to solve this, but I was wondering how we know that $dom(f): f \in S$ is a set such that $\bigcup dom(f): f \in S$ is a set by the axiom of union. I need this to be able to use the axiom of extensionality for the second part of the exercise.

The axioms that I know so far are:
1.) The axiom of the empty set: $\exists x \forall y$ $y\notin x$

2.) The axiom of extensionility: $\forall x \forall y (x=y \iff \forall z(z \in x \iff z \in y))$

3.) The axiom of pairing: $\forall x \forall y \exists z \forall t (t \in z \iff (t=x \lor t=y)$

4.) The axiom of union: $\forall x \exists y \forall z(z \in y \iff \exists s (s \in x$ $\land$ $z \in s))$

5.) The axiom of seperation: $\forall p \forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \iff (z \in x$ $\land$ $\varphi (z,p)))$

6.) The axiom of power set: $\forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \iff z \subseteq x)$

where $z \subseteq x$ is an abbreviation for $\forall t (t \in z \implies t \in x)$

If there were only two functions I could use the axiom of seperation, but there could be arbitrarily many. If I can find a set that contains $dom(f)$ for all $f \in S$, then I can use the axiom of seperation. How can I show this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical treatment would use the axiom of replacement, but this is not necessary.

We are looking to show that for any $f$, $dom(f) := \{x \mid \exists y ((x, y) \in f)\}$ is a set.

To do this, consider that $(x, y) = \{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$ by definition. So if $(x, y) \in f$, then we see that $x, y \in \{x, y\} \in (x, y) \in f$, and therefore $x, y \in \bigcup\bigcup f$.

Thus, we can construct $dom(f) = \{x \in \bigcup\bigcup f \mid \exists y \in \bigcup\bigcup f ((x, y) \in f)\}$. This is a set by the axiom scheme of separation (in fact, by the weaker scheme of $\Delta_0$-separation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I need to show is that there is a set that has the domains of the functions as its elements or in other words that the class $\{dom(f): f \in S \}$ is a set. What you've shown is that the domain of any function is a set, right?

Comment: I have shown that the domain of a relation exists. To show $\{dom(f) \mid f \in S\}$ is a set is a simple consequence of this, since the latter is a subset of $P(dom(\bigcup S))$.

Comment: Ok, I failed to see this, so thanks for pointing it out. Just to make sure I understand this: We know that  for any $f \in S$ $dom(f) \subseteq dom(\bigcup S)$ since $f \subseteq\bigcup S$. This means that $dom(f) \in P(dom(\bigcup S))$ and we can use the axiom of seperation to show that $\{dom(f): f \in S\}$ is a set, correct?

Comment: @DerivativesGuy Exactly right. Of course, the general method for proving such a set exists is replacement, but there are some interesting models of set theory where replacement isn’t available.